# Recuperación de proyecto eliminado por error?

Tags: visual-studio

Por error elimine todos los archivos de mi proyecto usando shift + supr, por tanto no está en la papelera. Exporte el archivo y ahora sólo tengo el msi a parte del .exe, ¿Qué podría hacer para recuperar mi proyecto?

Comment: Usa un programa para recuperar archivos y para la proxima, usa algun repositorio para manejar ramas, y tenes tu backup de forma mas profesional.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar IlSpy o DnSpy para descompilar tu exe y generar de nuevo la solución. Yo prefiero DnSpy.

https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/p/ilspy/9mxfbkfvsq13?activetab=pivot:overviewtab
https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/releases

También puedes utilizar recuva o algún programa similar para recuperar el archivo borrado.

https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva